# CakePHP view method using post title as url

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following link structure for my portfolio:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Portfolio']['title'], array('controller' => 'portfolio', 'action' => 'view', Inflector::slug($post['Portfolio']['title'])), array('title' => $post['Portfolio']['title'])); ?>
```

Which gives urls like: `http://driz.co.uk/portfolio/view/Paperview_Magazine`

However how do I get my controller to show the item based on the title?

So far I have this but have not been able to get it to work and just get a blank page (so I ALSO need to check the format is correct and that their is a relevant item)

```
function view ( $title )
{

    $posts = $this->Portfolio->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Portfolio.title' => $title)
    ));

    if (empty($title))
    {
        $this->cakeError('error404');
    }
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: It's highly likely your `$title` is invalid (spaces, invalid characters etc. You should use a URL friendly slug and pass that to your `view` function instead.

Comment: to clarify - even though you are using `Inflector::slug` on your $title, your `Portfolio.title` probably isn't stored as a slug. You would need to search for `Portfolio.slug` to ensure a match!

Comment: Okies I follow. Can you show me how to do this then? as for example in my DB the title will be saved as 'Paperview Magazine'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ross suggested that you search using Portfolio.slug so here's how you could do this:

1. Add a field to your database table called slug. You'll most likely want a VARCHAR with sufficient length to accommodate the slug.
2. When you create or update a "Portfolio" record, use the Inflector::slug method to generate a slug and save it to your database. You could always do this in the model's beforeSave event or if you prefer, in the controller before saving the data.
3. Update the find call to look for Portfolio.slug instead of Portfolio.title.

Unfortunately, there's no way to reverse the Inflector::Slug function as it removes certain characters like apostrophes, quotes, parentheses, etc. which is why you need to save the slug to your database if you want to search for it.

Here's how you could use the beforeSave event in your model:

```
public function beforeSave(array $options = array())
{
  // If the title is not empty, create/update the slug.
  if ( ! empty($this->data[$this->alias]['title'] )
    $this->data[$this->alias]['slug'] = Inflector::slug($this->data[$this->alias]['title']);

  // Returning true is important otherwise the save or saveAll call will fail.
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Could I not just Inflect the post title in the controller as well and them compare them (as they will then match) to get the correct post?

Comment: The problem with that method is that you'd have to fetch your entire Portfolio records and loop through them until you find the right one.  That would be extremely inefficient, especially as your database table grows.

Comment: Am I not already looping through them using the `find()` method?

Comment: No, find('first') only returns 1 row, not all of them. To achieve what you suggested above, you'd have to find('all') and loop throw each row.

Comment: Okay see here for my alternative idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324374/cakephp-using-the-tiny-library-to-create-permalinks if you can help with this it'd be awesome thanks

Comment: I've provided a solution to your alternative idea but why generate longer URLs when you can simply save the slug to your database?